# Opera App Store - How is Payment made to the developer?

Tags: app-store, opera, payment

I have checked on all over the Opera Admin console and cant see where they mention how payment is made. They state when it is made, but no how. i.e. Paypal, Cheque, etc.
Anybody know how they make a payment?

Answer (score 3):

Developers on Opera Mobile Store will have their money sent automatically when the amount reaches US$200.

Opera Mobile Store can send check (free), ACH transfer within USA (free), PayPal transfer (free) or wired transfer (bank charges US$45 for this).

Developers can also send us an email and ask to send any smaller amount of money, in such case money transferred on request.

Comment: Thanks for that. Due to my rep I can't plus your answer.